# FGSL configuration with local install of GSL

Tags: compilation, fortran, gsl, fgsl

I would like to use library `fgsl`, that depends on `gsl`. I have problem indicating where `gsl` is installed while configuring `fgsl`. I want to use the static version of these libraries. I can not use `gsl` library from Linux packages, these versions are not recent enough.

First I download, configure, compile and install `gsl` locally, i.e. using the `--prefix` option. (Instructions are presented below)

Then I download `fgsl`, configure it. This last operation fails because I do not succeed indicating where is `gsl`. I have tried to use `gsl_LIBS` unsuccessfully.

```
wget http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/gnu/gsl/gsl-2.3.tar.gz -O gsl.tar.gz
mkdir -p gsl_build && cd gsl_build
tar -xzf ../gsl.tar.gz --strip 1
autoreconf -fi
./configure CFLAGS="-Wall" --prefix `pwd`/../gsl
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf gsl_build
```

Here are the commands I run to install `fgsl`

```
wget https://github.com/reinh-bader/fgsl/archive/v1.2.0.tar.gz -O fgsl.tar.gz
mkdir -p fgsl_build
cd fgsl_build
tar -xzf ../fgsl.tar.gz --strip 1
autoreconf -fi
export gsl_LIBS=`pwd`/../gsl/lib
./configure CFLAGS="-Wall" FCFLAGS="-Wall" --prefix `pwd`/../fgsl --libdir=`pwd`/../gsl/lib --includedir=`pwd`/../gsl/include
make
make check
make install
cd ..
rm -rf fgsl_build
```

I try to do this for the open source project [AcousticBEM](https://github.com/Gjacquenot/AcousticBEM). Here is the [log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/287213575/log.txt?X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-Date=20171012T200716Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJRYRXRSVGNKPKO5A/20171012/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=d7727d3dc85e31c3b223e14dccf7958f6358f187686dc6a8b7d7c8a5465fb008) presenting the problem.

Comment: What is the relevant output from `configure`?  But you aren't specifying a complete link line, just a directory name.

Comment: I have tried with `export gsl_LIBS=`pwd`/../gsl/lib/libgsl.a;`pwd`/../gsl/lib/libgslcblas.a`, but without success

Comment: The output log is located at the end of this webpage: https://travis-ci.org/Gjacquenot/AcousticBEM

Comment: Some selected relevant part should be in the question so that it survives the changes of that website r deletion of your comment.

Comment: Have a look at the `    ./configure --prefix=<path to gsl install> \
                --libdir=<path to gsl install>/lib/$FC \
                --includedir=<path to gsl install>/include/$FC` part in the instructions for gsl: https://github.com/reinh-bader/fgsl and add the explicit error in your question.

Comment: Why the `$FC` in the install script paths? Also, you use `--prefix ../gsl` and your question is now out of sync...

Answer (score 1):

Well, here are my updated scripts to install `gsl` and `fgsl` locally. I have used `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to tell `fgsl` where `gsl` is installed. I end up with a directory named `gsl` containing `gsl` libraries and `fgsl` libraries.

First a shell script to install `gsl`

```
export gsl_INSTALL_DIR=`pwd`/gsl
[ -f ./gsl.tar.gz ] && echo "No need to download gsl" || wget http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/gnu/gsl/gsl-2.3.tar.gz -O gsl.tar.gz
mkdir -p gsl_build
cd gsl_build
tar -xzf ../gsl.tar.gz --strip 1
autoreconf -fi
./configure CFLAGS="-Wall" --prefix=${gsl_INSTALL_DIR}
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf gsl_build
```

Second, a script to install `fgsl` locally using the newly install `gsl`

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`pwd`/gsl/lib/pkgconfig
export gsl_LIBS=`pwd`/gsl
[ -f ./fgsl.tar.gz ] && echo "No need to download fgsl" || wget https://github.com/reinh-bader/fgsl/archive/v1.2.0.tar.gz -O fgsl.tar.gz
mkdir -p fgsl_build
cd fgsl_build
tar -xzf ../fgsl.tar.gz --strip 1
autoreconf -fi
./configure CFLAGS="-Wall" FCFLAGS="-Wall" --prefix=${gsl_LIBS}
make
make check
make install
cd ..
rm -rf fgsl_build
```